# not obtaining coverage code for ios 6 versions

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, xcode5, code-coverage

I am new to unit testing and code coverage area in iOS. I am using XCode 5 and I am doing iOS coding for iOS 6 and 7 versions, I have created a dummy project and written unit testing , but when I try to get code coverage, it showing error as no *.gcda* files found. I know the above error comes for iOS 7 but I don't know why the same error is coming for iOS 6 versions also. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer just visit the bubble foundry site with the above requiremens. you will get the required steps. Happy coding